# Função sem retorno no MatLab

Tags: funções, matlab

Preciso fazer uma função no matlab onde ela não terá nenhuma variável como retorno, apenas parâmetros, é possível?

Comment: o link responde à tua questâo? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81489-how-to-create-a-void-function-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionando ao [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81489-how-to-create-a-void-function-in-matlab) colocado anteriormente, uma funcão pode ser completamente vazia ou ter apenas parametros de entrada, basta não ter nada como saida. 
Exemplos:

```
%%Em um arquivo chamado v.m
function v(a,b)
% a funcão V cria uma figura e plota or argumentos "a" e "b"
figure()
hold on
plot(a,b)
```

ou

```
%%Em um arquivo chamado v.m
function v(a,b)
% esta funcão está vazia!
```

Exemplo de uma funcão com saida:

```
%%Em um arquivo chamado v.m    
function x=v(a,b)
%retorna a soma da soma dos vetores
x=sum(a)+sum(b);
```

Para chamar a funcão, use `v(a,b)`, em todos os casos.
Lembrando que é bom não usar nomes já existentes; O seu terá prioridade naquele diretório (ou em todos as lugares, caso esteja no *path*), mas pode causar confusão.